# Laravel sync() multiple rows at same time

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I'm trying to sync an Eloquent relationship (pivot table) using the `sync` method.  The below code works, but I was wondering if there was a better way to write it using Laravel?

```
$ids        = $this->role->whereIn('field', $request)->lists('id')->toArray();
$pivotData  = array_fill(0, count($ids), ['user_id' => $id]);
$roles      = array_combine($ids, $pivotData);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What means multiple rows? For example to attach multiple users to multiple roles?

Comment: Attach a user to multiple roles...yes

Comment: If you want one user to attach multiple rows: $user->roles()->sync([1, 2, 3]); If it's more user, I would iterate over it with a `foreach` if it's only a few user. In other case I would skip sync, and use simple query builder: `DB::table('role_user')->insert([['user_id' => 1, 'role_id' => 2], ['user_id' => 2, role_id=> 3]])`